# $\int_{\{x\in \mathbb{R^2};1\leq|x|\leq2\}}|\nabla f_0| \leq \int_{\{x\in \mathbb{R^2};1\leq|x|\leq2\}}|\nabla f|$

Tags: integration, inequality

Let $f_0:\{x\in \mathbb{R^2};1\leq|x|\leq2\} \to \mathbb{R}; f_0(x)=|x|-1$, and

$f \in C^1(\{x\in \mathbb{R^2};1\leq|x|\leq2\});|x|=1 \Rightarrow f(x)=0, |x|=2 \Rightarrow f(x)=1$.

Then $\int_{\{x\in \mathbb{R^2};1\leq|x|\leq2\}}|\nabla f_0| \leq \int_{\{x\in \mathbb{R^2};1\leq|x|\leq2\}}|\nabla f|$?

Comment: Possible (almost sure) typo: $f(x)=|x|-1$ is actually $f_0(x)=|x|-1$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.